# How to add gradient to the triangle?

Tags: css, gradient, linear-gradients

How would I be able to apply a gradient color to the triangle?

https://jsfiddle.net/otz9ewm8/

```
.spinner::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
  border-left: 27px solid #B76BF0;
  transform: translateX(4px);
  z-index: 0;
}
```

How would this be done in the code?

```css
.spinner {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  /*background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);*/
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  /* -webkit-mask: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), #000000 90%);*/
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform-origin: 50% 55%;
  transform: perspective(90px) rotateX(30deg);
  animation: spinner-wiggle 5.2s infinite;
}

.spinner::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
  border-left: 27px solid #B76BF0;
  transform: translateX(4px);
  z-index: 0;
}




@keyframes spinner-wiggle {
  30% {
    transform: perspective(90px) rotateX(10deg);
  }

  40% {
    transform: perspective(90px) rotateX(7deg);
  }

  50% {
    transform: perspective(90px) rotateX(10deg);
  }

  60% {
    transform: perspective(90px) rotateX(8deg);
  }
}

.color-circle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear,
      left top,
      left bottom,
      color-stop(50%, #25d8fb),
      color-stop(100%, #4f66bb));
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 0;
  box-shadow: inset 0 24px 18px -10px rgba(0, 0, 140, 0.3),
    inset 0 0 22px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  cursor: pointer;

  background: linear-gradient(100deg, #24A4EA, #379DEB 25%, #B76BF0);
  -webkit-mask-image: radial-gradient(circle, transparent 0 36px, black 36px);
  mask-image: radial-gradient(circle, transparent 0 50px, black 20px);
}

.spinner:hover .color-circle {
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear,
      left top,
      left bottom,
      color-stop(50%, rgba(34, 204, 0, 0.9)),
      color-stop(100%, #55ff00));
}

.color-circle:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 72px;
  height: 72px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #353198;
  z-index: 0;
}

.spinner:hover .color-circle {
  animation: spin 1.7s infinite linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotateZ(0deg);
  }

  100% {
    transform: rotateZ(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class=" spinner">
    <span class="color-circle"></span>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [clip-path instead of borders](https://jsfiddle.net/fqtarhk0/)

```
  background-image: linear-gradient(100deg, #24A4EA, #379DEB 25%, #B76BF0);
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 50%, 0% 100%);
```